# Should an Active Directory network use IPv6 unique local addresses in addition to global addresses?

Tags: active-directory, dhcp, ipv6

Should an Active Directory network use IPv6 unique local addresses in addition to global addresses?

If so, should those be distributed using DHCPv6?

Also, if a DHCPv6 server is distributing unique local addresses, will clients still listen and process router advertisements for global addresses?

Answer (score 1):

1) "Should" according to who/what? I don't think there is a standard. I certainly don't use ULA addresses as well at global addresses on my AD hosts.

2) Servers should always have static addresses. It's up to you if you use SLAAC or DHCPv6 for clients.

3) In my experience, no. The RA will still be processed, but the client should see the flags in the RA telling it to use DHCPv6, and do that *instead* of creating a SLAAC address.